# CoreData Migration Local Store -> iCloud Store

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

I have the following problem.
I have successfully created my iCloud Magical Record Store and also works great if you filled it from zero :)

But now I have many data in the old Magical Record Local Store and I want to take this to the iCloud store.
But how i can migrate them.

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken]) {
    [self iCloudCoreDataSetup]} 
else {
    NSLog(@"iCloud not enabled");
    [MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
}
```

Here i am checking iCloud is available. Before iCloud, i have always initialized with

```
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
```

Here is my code for the iCloud Installation

```
- (void)iCloudCoreDataSetup {
// containerID should contain the same string as your iCloud entitlements
NSString *containerID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iCloud.%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:containerID
                                      contentNameKey:@"App"                // Must not contain dots
                                     localStoreNamed:@"App.sqlite"
                             cloudStorePathComponent:@"Documents/CloudLogs"     // Subpath within your ubiquitous container that will contain db change logs
                                          completion:^{
                                              // This gets executed after all the setup steps are performed
                                              // Uncomment the following lines to verify
                                              NSLog(@"%@", [MagicalRecord currentStack]);
                                              // NSLog(@"%i events", [Event countOfEntities]);
                                          }];

// NOTE: MagicalRecord's setup is asynchronous, so at this point the default persistent store is still probably NIL!
// Uncomment the following line if you want to check it.
NSLog(@"%@", [MagicalRecord currentStack]);

// The persistent store COORDINATOR is however fully setup and can be accessed
// Uncomment the following line if you want to check it.
 NSLog(@"Store coordinator at this point %@", [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator]);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Finally, store change notifications must be observed. Without these, your app will NOT function properly!
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// This notification is issued only once when
// 1) you run your app on a particular device for the first time
// 2) you disable/enable iCloud document storage on a particular device
// usually a couple of seconds after the respective event.
// The notification must be handled on the MAIN thread and synchronously
// (because as soon as it finishes, the persistent store is removed by OS).
// Refer to Apple's documentation for further details
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification
                                                  object:[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator]
 // queue:nil    // Run on the posting (i.e. background) thread
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]   // Run on the main thread
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  // For debugging only
                                                  NSLog(@"%s notificationBlockWillChange:%@, isMainThread = %i", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, note, [NSThread isMainThread]);

                                                  // Disable user interface with setEnabled: or an overlay
                                                  // NOTE: Probably not crucial since the store switch is almost instantaneous.
                                                  //       I only hint it here by changing the tint color to red.
                                                  self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

                                                  // Save changes to current MOC and reset it
                                                  if ([[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] hasChanges]) {
                                                      [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
                                                  }
                                                  [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] reset];

                                                  // TODO: Drop any managed object references here
                                              }];

// This notification is issued couple of times every time your app starts
// The notification must be handled on the BACKGROUND thread and asynchronously to prevent deadlock
// Refer to Apple's documentation for further details
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator]
                                                   queue:nil    // Run on the posting (i.e. background) thread
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  // For debugging only
                                                  NSLog(@"%s notificationBlockDidChange:%@, isMainThread = %i", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, note, [NSThread isMainThread]);

                                                  // This block of code must be executed asynchronously on the main thread!
                                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                      // Recommended by Apple
                                                      [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] reset];

                                                      // Notify UI that the data has changes
                                                      // NOTE: I am using the same notification that MagicalRecord sends after merging changes
                                                      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kMagicalRecordPSCDidCompleteiCloudSetupNotification object:nil];

                                                      // Re-enable user interface with setEnabled: or removing the overlay
                                                      // NOTE: Probably not crucial since the store switch is almost instantaneous.
                                                      //       I only hint it here by changing the tint color back to default.
                                                      self.window.tintColor = nil;
                                                  });
                                              }];
}
```

But how can I take the old data from the local store to iCloud?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know anything about MagicRecord but check here for sample apps and code for migration to and from iCloud.  http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/